# How to override generic repository error message

Tags: java, c#, typescript, domain-driven-design, repository-pattern

I have GenericRepository class that has all the basic functionality for interacting with persistence storage (create, find, get all, delete, update)

In `find` method, I'm searching from the database with its primary key. It will throw exception if data not found

This generic repository class is inherited by some other classes. I would like to get some more clear error message about what kind of data is not found.

So if my OrderRepository's find method cannot find any data, I want the error message to show me that 'Order is not found', not the generic message 'Data not found'

Are there any best practices on how to achieve this functionality?

I'm using Typescript for my project

Answer (score 1):

First, you shouldn't throw exceptions for operations such as empty result sets from a 'find' in your repository.

Instead, you should return an empty collection, instead of a null or exception.

Comment: The find method returns a single entity, not collections. I use my `get all` to get collections

Comment: One, many, it doesn't matter. The whole idea is that you shouldnt' throw exceptions for operations of that kind. Use Exceptions for things you cannot recover from and you need them to re-issue.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, if you are aiming for applying DDD properly, it would be better not to use generic form of repository. It would make some problems in the future like showing custom messages. If different repositories were added, every message, that you like, could easily be shown.
If some messages such as "**Data** not found" are common you can use a method in a class like utility that returns a proper message according to the entity type.